# Why am I getting "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again"

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm pretty sure my problem is somewhere in this part of my code. If I change <form action="/update/{id}"to login, I can get all the routes running the way they should and allowing the user to enter a new password and send them to the login screen. But I can not figure out how to get it to save that password and then let the user login with the new password.

```
@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def update(id):
form = UpdatePasswordForm()
userPass = User.query.get(id)
if request.method == "POST":
    userPass.password = request.form['password']


    try:
        db.session.commit()
        flash("User Updated Successfully!")
        return render_template("update.html",
                               form=form,
                               userPass=userPass,
                               id=id)
        redirect(url_for('login'))

    except:
        flash("Error! There was a problem changing your password")
        return render_template("update.html",
                               form=form,
                               userPass=userPass,
                               id=id)
        redirect(url_for('update'))
else:
    return render_template("update.html",
                           form=form,
                           userPass=userPass,
                           id=id)
    redirect(url_for('update'))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Update Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Update Password</h1>

<form action="/update/{id}" method="POST">
    {{ form.password(class="form-control", value=userPass.password) }}
    {{ form.submit}}

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe you need `<form action="/update/{{id}}"...`.  Jinja requires two curly brackets for substitution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing some brackets here in the id variable

```
<form action="/update/{id}" method="POST">
```

It should be instead

```
<form action="/update/{{id}}" method="POST">
```

Jinja needs double curly braces for variables. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#variables